# UIImageView remains blank

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I created a ViewController and then attached ImageViewController to it.
here are my interface and implementation. When I run they program it doesn't show the image, only a blank view.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ImageViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *myImageView;

@end
```

implementation

```
#import "ImageViewController.h"

@interface ImageViewController ()

@end


@implementation ImageViewController

@synthesize myImageView;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //create an image

    //create an image
    UIImage *myScreenShot = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lips_PNG6197.png"];

    //image view instance to display the image
    self.myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myScreenShot];

    //set the frame for the image view
    CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, self.myImageView.frame.size.width,
                                self.myImageView.frame.size.height/2);
    [self.myImageView setFrame:myFrame];

    //If your image is bigger than the frame then you can scale it
    [self.myImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

    //add the image view to the current view
    [self.view addSubview:self.myImageView];
   }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Note that i checked that UIImage is not nil in debugger. Also I am not creating UIImageView via IB.
Any suggestions on what is going wrong i.e. why am I not seeing the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not creating the image view in IB then this is your problem:

```
 CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, self.myImageView.frame.size.width,
                                self.myImageView.frame.size.height/2);
```

Your telling it the width and height should be based off `self.myImageView` which hasn't been created yet so it's 0. So here this is what your essentially saying:

```
CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 0.0, 0.0);
```

I'm assuming what you might want is this:

```
 CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, self.view.frame.size.width,
                                self.view.frame.size.height/2);
```

Comment: Correct, and also remember that viewDidLoad is not the right place to set frames, it happens too early. You should do it in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here

```
//set the frame for the image view
CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, self.myImageView.frame.size.width,
                            self.myImageView.frame.size.height/2);
[self.myImageView setFrame:myFrame];
```

Debug these lines and you will notice that `self.myImageView.frame.size.height` and `self.myImageView.frame.size.width` are actually zero.

`self.myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myScreenShot];` will not set frame size for you.

If you are looking to use the image's height/width you have to use, `myScreenShot.size` and if you are looking to use the view's frame then `self.view.frame.size`

Answer (score 1):

Both the answers already given point in the right direction, if you wanted the imageview to be the size of the image, you could replace this line of code

```
CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, self.myImageView.frame.size.width,
                                self.myImageView.frame.size.height/2);
```

With this

```
CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, myScreenShot.size.width,
                                myScreenShot.size.height);
```

I don't know why you'll want to do this. Its safer to initialize the UIImageView with a frame you are well familiar with, so maybe try to use distinct values to suit your design. e.g

```
CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 300.0f,250.0f);
```